# C# Mount network drive using WNetAddConnection2 gives 87 error

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to mount a network drive using c# and WNetAddConnection2 but i am getting always error 87 (Invalid Parameter) and do not know which parameter is incorrect.

So first i created a static internal helper class:

```
static class InternalHelpers
{
    [DllImport("mpr.dll")]
    private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(
    ref NETRESOURCE netResource,
    string password,
    string username,
    int flags);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private class NETRESOURCE
    {
        public int dwScope;
        public int dwType;
        public int dwDisplayType;
        public int dwUsage;
        public string lpLocalName;
        public string lpRemoteName;
        public string lpComment;
        public string lpProvider;
    }

    public static bool MapNetworkDrive(string driveLetter, string networkPath, string username, string password)
    {
        NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE
        {
            dwType = 0x1,
            lpLocalName = $"{driveLetter}:",
            lpRemoteName = networkPath
        };

        int result = WNetAddConnection2(ref nr, password, username, 0);

        if (result != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(result);
            //return false;
        }
        else return true;
    }
}
```

I call the `MapNetworkDrive` method as follows:

```
InternalHelpers.MapNetworkDrive(DriveLetter, UncPath, Username, Password);
```

With the following parameters:

```
("Z", @"\\10.1.100.126\codes", "Administrator", "1")
```

What is causing error 87.
I tried with and without the trailing \ after the path with no success.

Comment: `NETRESOURCE` looks awfully non-native. I'm not sure that it can be properly marshaled by the P/Invoke type marshaler. Why not have [C#/Win32](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32) generate those declarations for you?

Comment: Try to [Retrieve Information About a Network Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/retrieving-information-about-a-network-resource) to identify the network provider, `\\10.1.100.126\codes`, owns a resource or [Enumerate Network Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wnet/enumerating-network-resources).